# What is the return value when you call a non-existent function and the call goes through to the fallback?

Tags: solidity

Say I am expecting a result to be returned. What will happen to the return value when the call will go through to the fallback since the fallback does not return anything?

> uint a = otherContract.bar();

where I expect bar to return uint but `otherContract` does not actually implement it

> function bar () returns (uint);

Will `a` take a value? will the cal throw?

Answer (score 0):

The call will `revert`. In the below code, I created two contracts `A` and `B`, one of which has no functions, and another has empty `fallback`. I have written within the code the sequence of deployment and calls to check in Remix.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicensed
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

interface IA {
    function checkBool() external returns(bool);
    function checkUint() external returns(uint256);
}

// 1. Deploy A
contract A {
}

interface IB {
    function checkBool() external returns(bool);
    function checkUint() external returns(uint256);
}

// 2. Deploy B
contract B {
    fallback() external {
    }
}

// 3. Deploy C
contract C {
    event BoolEvent(bool);
    event UintEvent(uint256);

    // 4. Call this function with Deployed A
    function checkBoolA(address _A) public {
        emit BoolEvent(IA(_A).checkBool());
    }

    // 5. Call this function with Deployed B
    function checkBoolB(address _B) public {
        emit BoolEvent(IB(_B).checkBool());
    }

    // 6. Call this function with Deployed A
    function checkUintA(address _A) public {
        emit UintEvent(IA(_A).checkUint());
    }

    // 7. Call this function with Deployed B
    function checkUintB(address _B) public {
        emit UintEvent(IB(_B).checkUint());
    }
}
```